# Is 'bologna' acceptable for 'baloney' in the sense of nonsense?

Tags: american-english, slang

A recent NYTimes [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/05/22/technology/google-antitrust.html) about the state of antitrust cases against Google had the line:

> Most of this is bologna and distracts us from the only question that
>   matters

Which seems like an over-correction. Does it make sense to back-form what we'd ordinarily call **baloney** into **bologna**?

I see other questions about **baloney** on this SE but none that go in this direction.

Comment: I'll note that, here in the US Midwest, I've rarely heard it pronounced any way other than "baloney", whether it was the meat product or the words spewing from a politician's mouth.

Comment: I would hesitate for a _very_ long time before deciding that something in the New York Times needed correcting. I would call their use of 'bologna' witty and fresh.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey is right. When faced with a cliché or a tired expression (like *baloney*), good writers will work (yes, it involves work) to find something to freshen the prose and thereby wake up the reader. Calling it *bologna* forces the reader to view the trope in a new light.

Comment: This is not a reporter's news article but opinion & analysis, so she can write how she wishes. (Reminds of saying the original dish was Welsh Rarebit. Sure it was, get a sense of humor.)

Comment: @Robusto & Michael Harvey, I take it your answer is that this use of the word is **not** generally acceptable for ordinary communication, but it may be regarded as creative pushing of the boundaries of what is acceptable, which can be effective in the right kind of context. To put it more casually, your answer is: this is OK in a NYT article, but don't try it yourself, unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @jsw29: No. Go ahead and try it yourself *if you can pull it off*. If your writing is poor in other areas it might look like a mistake, but if you can express yourself with style and grace, I think you should *always* try for freshness of expression. Readers of the *Post* might not get it, but the *Daily News* crowd would not think anything is amiss.

Comment: @Robusto, in order to 'pull it off', one needs to know what one is doing: one needs to understand that this is a somewhat non-standard use of the word (but not so non-standard that it would be difficult to understand), and to then consciously choose to use the word in that non-standard way in order to 'wake up the reader'. The (arguable) freshness of this use of the word and its ability to 'wake up the reader' depends precisely on its being non-standard. If it becomes standard, it will cease to be fresh.

Comment: jsw29: I think it's pretty far from standard.  I slso think you're misunderstanding my intent, though. I'm not encouraging you to copy that particular usage,  but to go for freshness in your writing.